# How can I know how much memory each loaded R package is taking up?

Tags: r, package

Whether I want to load a package that contains a function that I want versus writing my own function depends largely on the size of the package. How I can get the size of the package (without looking through my directories) with code? Also, is there code that can tell me how much memory each of my loaded/attached packages are taking up in my workspace?

Comment: I don't think packages tend to take up that much memory, relative to the size of any reasonably sized dataset. Have you run into any actual problems when loading multiple packages?

Comment: No. I thought maybe I would eventually. 
This was bothering me because I wouldn't want to run into a problem with memory after having spent a lot of time relying on a package. I would rather just weigh the costs and benefits of using a package versus righting my own code.  
So it's really never a concern? There aren't big, useful packages out there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Loading packages does not take much memory. You can use `mem_used()` function from package `pryr` to estimate the memory growth with each package being loaded:

```
library(pryr)

mem_used()
# 74.1 MB

library(dplyr)
mem_used()
# 77 MB

library(data.table)
mem_used()
#78.2 MB
```